# How to check if csrf_token matches cookies' csrftoken in processing callback View?

Tags: django-views, callback, django-middleware, csrf-token

I'm new to Django. And sorry advance that I'm not good at speaking English.

I spent a whole day searching for relevant information on Google. But I can't solve my problem.

First, my goal is: I try to make social-login enable in my apps using django. With my Googling, I would find a code which I can refer to.
([link](https://khs9628.github.io/2019/09/22/CBV6/) - above mentioned code)

(and [Naver Social Login API Refference](https://developers.naver.com/docs/login/devguide/devguide.md#3-4-2-%EB%84%A4%EC%9D%B4%EB%B2%84-%EB%A1%9C%EA%B7%B8%EC%9D%B8-%EC%97%B0%EB%8F%99-url-%EC%83%9D%EC%84%B1%ED%95%98%EA%B8%B0) - You may need a translator. )

Following this code, I try ...

STEP I. Sending user to login page which Social company provide.

```
login_form.html

<a href="#" onclick="naverLogin()">
```

And at that time, attach csrf_token to params "state"

```
// user/static/user/js/social_login.js

function buildQuery(params) {
    return Object.keys(params).map(function (key) {return key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key])}).join('&')
}
function buildUrl(baseUrl, queries) {
    return baseUrl + '?' + buildQuery(queries)
}

function naverLogin() {
    params = {
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id:'lkfcHFxyz5UGC0gF81Ym',
        redirect_uri: location.origin + '/user/login/social/naver/callback/' + location.search,
        state: document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value
    }
    url = buildUrl('https://nid.naver.com/oauth2.0/authorize', params)
    location.replace(url)
}
```

STEP II. User(Client) try to login on Social Login Page.

STEP III. Making SocialLoginCallbackView(NaverMixins, View):

```
class SocialLoginCallbackView(NaverLoginMixin, View):

    success_url = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
    failure_url = settings.LOGIN_URL
    required_profiles = ['email', 'nickname']

    model = get_user_model()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        provider = kwargs.get('provider')
        success_url = request.GET.get('next', self.success_url)

        if provider == 'naver': 
            csrf_token = request.GET.get('state')
            code = request.GET.get('code')
            if not _compare_salted_tokens(csrf_token, request.COOKIES.get('csrftoken')):
                messages.error(request, 'Login Failed ......', extra_tags='danger')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.failure_url)
            is_success, error = self.login_with_naver(csrf_token, code)
            if not is_success: # login failed
                messages.error(request, error, extra_tags='danger')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url if is_success else self.failure_url)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.failure_url)

    def set_session(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            self.request.session[key] = value
```

I can't continue to... beacause of this function (_compare_salted_tokens).
My django ver. 4.2 But, above django ver. 2.1.3

In django ver. 4.2, I can't find _compare_salted_tokens function. I finally reallized much difference between django.middleware.csrf (in django ver 4.2) and (in django ver 2.1).

```
if not _compare_salted_tokens(csrf_token, request.COOKIES.get('csrftoken')):
```

How could i achieve this purpose ? (in Django 4.2 ways or alternative ways or ? )

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

I want to replace function (_compare_salted_tokens) to any method suitable for Django 4.2